# How to add one day to the current date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to add one day to the current date heres my code :

```
 var dt = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
 alert(dt);
 dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
 alert("date plus one day is : "+dt);
```

thats gave me an error:

> TypeError: dt.getDate is not a function

can anybody help please??

Comment: `dt` is a filter not a date

Comment: so how can i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 6):

Add one day to date before the filter.

```
 var sdate = new Date();
 sdate.setDate(sdate.getDate() + 1);
 var dt = $filter('date')(sdate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$filter){
  
  var sdate = new Date();
  alert(sdate);
  sdate.setDate(sdate.getDate() + 1);
 var dt = $filter('date')(sdate, "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
 alert("date plus one day is : "+dt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: @abdellatif zoumhane no prob. make sure to mark it as right answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) you can use -

```
moment().add(1, 'days')
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var dt = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

To

```
var dt = new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/4hfL2wxz/8/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use Maths

```js
var currenttimestamp = new Date().getTime();
var currentdate=new Date().getDate();
var onedayaftertimestamp=currenttimestamp+(86400000);//1 day=86400000 ms;
var ondayafterdate=new Date(onedayaftertimestamp).getDate();

console.log("Current date:"+currentdate+"\n");
console.log("Ondayafterdate:"+ondayafterdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the date on the filter itself.

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

var dt = $filter('date')(tomorrow, "yyyy-MM-dd");
alert(dt);
```